# TSQL First of last month - date only

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is using SQL2008 R2.
I am trying to get the first of the last month in these two formats:
'06/01/2013' 
'2013-06-01'

I found this code, but it includes the time:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
```

My stored procedures want only the date.
I tried this to trim off the time, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT RIGHT(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0),8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want appears to be different character style outputs which are [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)..

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0), 111)

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
convert(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0), 101)
```

Here is another fun way... I am typing from my nexus, please forgive this

```
Select cast(cast(getdate() as int) as datetime),getdate()
```

Comment: Select cast(cast(getdate() as int) as datetime),getdate()

Answer (score 0):

try this,  it has no string conversions ...

```
declare @dt DateTime = getDate()
Select DateAdd(mm,-1, DateAdd(day, 1-day(@dt), 
               datediff(day, 0, @dt)))
```

or ...

```
declare @dt DateTime = getDate()
Select DateAdd(mm,-1, DateAdd(day, 0, 
              datediff(day, day(@dt)-1, @dt)))
```

or, even simpler,....

```
declare @dt DateTime = getDate()
select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 1, @dt)-1, 0)
```

or, making it allow for arbitrary months back...

```
declare @dt DateTime = getDate()
declare @monthsBack tinyInt = 3
select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 1, @dt) - @monthsBack, 0)
```

Comment: That returns June 30, not June 1.

Comment: thought you wanted the last of the last month. I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your question essentially boils down to how to convert a `datetime` to a `date`.  Like this:

```
CONVERT(date, someDate)
```

So, combine that with the code you already have to get the date you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))
```